# jQuery Tools Srollable, object has no method autoscroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable, jquery-scrollable

I'm using the Carousel for Plone v1.6 for a carousel. Initialising the carousel works fine but after that everything fails. I got this code:

```
var api = jQuery("div.scrollable").scrollable({
   size: 1,
   clickable: false,
   loop: true,
   circular: true
}).autoscroll().navigator({ navi:'.navi > a' });
```

The browser drops a javascript error which says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autoscroll'

Also the navigator method fails. If I drop those two methods and simply initialise the scrollable object, it works.

jQuery Tools 1.2.5 is in use and gets called before this script. I have no idea what could be wrong?!

Comment: Honestly, I believe your lib may be out-of-date. The only reason (given your explanation) that code would not work is 1) scrollable method doesn't return the jQuery object, or 2) the lib version you're using doesn't support the autoscroll method.

Unfortunately, it looks more like the latter suggestion I just gave. Update your jq-plugin lib.

Comment: Why not try doing:

var api = [...];
console.log(api);
api.autoscroll().navigation({...})... blah, blah.

Comment: I now have updated jQuery Tools to the latest version and jQuery itself to 1.8.3.
Still no luck.
console.log shows me this on the api object:
[div.scrollable, prevObject: v.fn.v.init[1], context: document, selector: "div.scrollable", constructor: function, init: function…]